# How to convert a png image to a JPG2000 format

Tags: java

I am capturing a person image passport using webcam lib.The genereated image is infor of png. I want to create a temporaly png file then convert that png file into JPG2000 format. How can I achieve this in java? here is my sample code n java

```
   webcam.open();
            BufferedImage image = webcam.getImage();
            imagePath = "";
           File temppngfile = new File(imagePath);

            ImageIO.write(image, "png", temppngfile);
```

Comment: Why don't you write your temporary PNG file in a PNG format ?

Comment: @Berger I want to convert the png file to jpeg2000 format that my main aim

Comment: Could you try "jpeg 2000" instead of "j2k" ? Also what is the output , and do you have any errors ?

Comment: @Berger I dont have any error. When I use png the file is generated successfully but when I try any other format it doesnt work at all